# how to display title bar after scrolling ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimage

i have view controller modally presented . it has one image view and uilabel, tableview underneath. 
once image hide when scroll, i would like to show title bar with text and decrease the opacity of image.

I tried with

`- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
 //taking image offset . nothing worked. please help
}`

thanks for your time and help

Comment: Is the delegate method being called?

Comment: yes. but i dont have idea to start with to solve this.